# Activecollab module : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: php, ajax, content-management-system, project, activecollab

I am working on ActiveCollab module, and facing a serious problem that never comes before. When I start development a simple module with simple index.tpl file ( with static text) , activecollab allows installs it successfully and working all things when I click somewhere in the project after installation without refreshing page, But when I refresh a page by F5 all body text disappears and nothing works in activecollab, I execute that page in Firefox it shows in firebug:

```
Firefox:
to much recursion 
to much recursion 
to much recursion 
to much recursion 
....
....
```

and when I run it in Chrome to identify problem then it shows some thing like:

```
Chrome:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
App.Wireframe.PageTitle.set
App.Wireframe.PageTitle.set
App.Wireframe.PageTitle.set
App.Wireframe.PageTitle.set
App.Wireframe.PageTitle.set
....
....
```

I checked activecollab logs file but there is no error found for this, would be really great for me if anyone helps me to resolve this issue.

**Updating Post:** 
as requested my controller code; below is my controller:

```
<?php

 AngieApplication::useController('backend', ENVIRONMENT_FRAMEWORK_INJECT_INTO);

  class PeopleCommissioningRequestController extends BackendController {


       function __construct($parent, $context = null) {
          parent::__construct($parent, $context);
       } 

        function __before() {
          parent::__before();
        } 

        function index() {
                 $this->response->assign( array('data' => 'test') );
        }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in your controller logic. Please paste controller action code so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: i have updated post with my controller code, please take a look on post ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved above issue .. that was just because of long length of module name .. I think that is activecollab bug ..

@llija many thanks for your help ..

Comment: We are not aware of such issue. How long was the name?